# React Query Error: Query data cannot be undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I get the error in the title when refetching the data several times after it loads for the first time. It seems like a random error.

I am displaying an error message with the `isError` Boolean flag.

Is there a way to mitigate this error? Or perhaps instead of displaying the error message, keep displaying the stale data to the user (perhaps with an alert)?

The full error is this:

```
Error: Query data cannot be undefined
    at Object.onSuccess (index.js:1099:19)
    at resolve (index.js:564:50)
```

Comment: I would fix the error instead of suppressing it.

Comment: I agree... I just can't seem to figure out why the errors occurs in the first place. Especially since it doesn't happen on first render, only when refetching the same data

Comment: It's probably related to the query function you wrote

Comment: Do you have conditions in your query function? This error can occur if you don't return anything from your query function or you return `undefined`.

Comment: You're right, turned out when I added `?? []` to my query function. I'm getting an empty array, so the response I'm getting is `undefined` is that a server error, or is there something I can do?

Comment: you have to show your code please. The error should also be accompanied with a more descriptive error log message in development mode. It means that your queryFn returned `undefined` and that is not allowed since v4: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4#undefined-is-an-illegal-cache-value-for-successful-queries